# how to fix font appearance on a remote terminal?

Tags: server, 16.04, fonts, emacs

after logging in to my terminal server via ssh kyes, I use the text editor emacs24 instead of the default `nano`, but no matter how I change the font, the system doesn't seem to pick that font. Adding insult to injury, when I use an Arabic font they appear like separated letters not connected as they should be.

[image]

Ubuntu 16.04 on server and updated.
my custom fonts were installed on root path `/usr/share/fonts/mycustomfonts` and then in that dir I ran: `sudo fc-cache -f -v` to cache all fonts there. When I fire up emacs on server it doesn't seem to pick anything when I change to Arabic input method, what am I missing?

Note: I have the same setting for emacs and fonts on my local machine running Ubuntu 16.04 with no issues, so leaving me with one conclustion that server machine is lacking something related to fonts. Your help to identify the problem would be much appreciated.